# Properties of an interesting summation $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1} }{2k+1}$

Tags: summation

Here I found a summation from somewhere : $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^{k+1} }{2k+1}$$

Is it a famous summation? I've heard that it's a *"special summation and irrational"*. Can anyone provide me a proof?

Comment: Yes.  It is $1-\pi/4$.  Write the series for $\arctan (x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\arctan(x)$.  Then, we have $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\arctan(x)&=f(x)=\int_0^x \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x'^{2n}\,dx'\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
\end{align}$$

Hence,

$$\pi/4=\arctan(1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$

and so, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n+1}=1-\frac\pi4$$

Answer (score 1):

If you start the sum at $k=0$ you get $$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k+1}=-\frac{\pi}{4}$$ If you insist on starting at $k=1$ then there is just a simple shift, so you get
$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k+1}=-\frac{\pi}{4}+1$$
See here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k + 1} \over 2k + 1} & =
1 + \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{\bracks{\pars{2k + 1} + 1}/2} \over 2k + 1} =
1 + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{\pars{k + 1}} \over k}\,
{1 - \pars{-1}^{k} \over 2}
\\[5mm] & =
1 + {1 \over 2}\,\ic\bracks{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{k} \over k} -
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-\ic}^{k} \over k}} =
1 - \Im\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{k} \over k} =
1 + \Im\ln\pars{1 - \ic}
\\[5mm] & =
1 + \Im\bracks{\ln\pars{\root{1^{2} + \pars{-1}^{2}}} + \arctan\pars{-1 \over \phantom{-}1}\,\ic} = \bbx{1 - {\pi \over 4}} \approx 0.2146
\end{align}

Comment: Wow, I like your solution

Comment: @Mathbg Thanks. You're welcome.